# Is it possible to get quantile by the exact value in python?

Tags: python, quantile

I get the quantile of the standard normal distribution (e.g. at 0.9 value). I use `scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.9, 0, 1)` for it.

I need to find the corresponding quantile to this value in my custom data. So I have to round value I got from `scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.9, 0, 1)` and then find its quantile. Is there any dedicated package function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

mean = 0
std = 1
N = 1000
quantile = 0.9

dist = stats.norm(mean, std)
x = dist.rvs(size = N)

data_quantile = np.quantile(x, quantile)
dist_quantile = dist.ppf(quantile)

print(f'The 0.9th quantile of the dataset is {data_quantile}')
#The 0.9th quantile of the dataset is 1.2580295186126398
print(f'The 0.9th quantile of the actual distribution is {dist_quantile}')
#The 0.9th quantile of the actual distribution is 1.2815515655446004
```

**EDIT**

However, I may be misinterpreting and after re-reading I am wondering if you actually want to do this:

```
def get_effective_quantile(dataset, distribution, quantile):
    dist_quantile = distribution.ppf(quantile)
    effective_quantile = sum(dataset <= dist_quantile) / len(dataset)
    return(effective_quantile)

print(f'The effective quantile of {dist_quantile} in the dataset is {get_effective_quantile(x, dist, quantile)}')
#The effective quantile of 1.2815515655446004 in the dataset is 0.904
```

I am unaware of a package or function that does that, but the above function is pretty straightforward and seems simpler and more robust than what you are currently doing based on your description.

Comment: Yeah, the second one is what I needed. I did it myself as well with 
```index_emp_q = (np.abs(data-theor_q)).argmin()



emp_q = index_emp_q / len(data)```
But for some reason it always has +1 in the last number digit. Haven't figured out yet why.